# JSON - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am outputting the results of my machine learning model into a JSON file but my python code isn't parsing the file correctly. I don't know what is causing it but I know it is my python code and not anything on the ML side of it The code is supposed to run through the JSON file and find out if the results are within a certain distance of each other (0.10).
My Error:

```
  File "vision.py", line 102, in <module>
    find_xy(18, 18)
  File "vision.py", line 61, in find_xy
    x_dif = obj1["relative_coordinates"]["center_x"] - obj2["relative_coordinates"]["center_x"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

My JSON file(`result.json`):

```
[
{
 "frame_id":1, 
 "filename":"Captures/Capevent4/capture0.png", 
 "objects": [ 
  {"class_id":17, "name":"g ", "relative_coordinates":{"center_x":0.789288, "center_y":0.412911, "width":0.339110, "height":0.789139}, "confidence":0.986945}, 
  {"class_id":17, "name":"g ", "relative_coordinates":{"center_x":0.657672, "center_y":0.411369, "width":0.226476, "height":0.744315}, "confidence":0.532443}, 
  {"class_id":17, "name":"g ", "relative_coordinates":{"center_x":0.736259, "center_y":0.559810, "width":0.409916, "height":0.651102}, "confidence":0.474929}
 ] 
}
]
```

My Code:

```
Save New Duplicate & Edit Just Text Twitter
results_path = r'result.json'

# function for formatting after every new picture is run through model

with open(results_path, 'r') as opened_results: 

    results = json.load(opened_results)

with open(results_path, "w") as opened_results:

    json.dump(results, opened_results, indent=4)

def find_xy(id1, id2):

    desired_id1 = id1
    obj1 = None

    for thing in results:

        for object1 in thing["objects"]:
            if object1["class_id"] == desired_id1:
                specific_class = object1
                obj1 = object1
                print("Correct Class")

                break

    for _class in results:

        for object1 in _class["objects"]:
            relative_coordinates = object1["relative_coordinates"]
            center_x = relative_coordinates["center_x"]
            center_y = relative_coordinates["center_y"]
            # Do something with these values

    desired_id2 = id2
    obj2 = None
    for thing in results:

        for object2 in thing["objects"]:

            if object2["class_id"] == desired_id2:
                specific_class = object2
                obj2 = object2
                print("Correct Class")
                break
    for _class in results:

        for object2 in _class["objects"]:

            relative_coordinates = object2["relative_coordinates"]
            center_x = relative_coordinates["center_x"]
            center_y = relative_coordinates["center_y"]

    x_dif = obj1["relative_coordinates"]["center_x"] - obj2["relative_coordinates"]["center_x"]

    x_absolute_dif = abs(x_dif)
    print("X Absolute Dif Is:" + str(x_absolute_dif))
 
   if (x_absolute_dif <= 0.10):

        print("X-Cords Within Range") 
        x_within_range = True
    else:
        print("X-Cords Not Within Range")
        x_within_range = False

    y_dif = obj1["relative_coordinates"]["center_y"] - obj2["relative_coordinates"]["center_y"]

    y_absolute_dif = abs(y_dif)
    print("Y Absolute Difference Is: " + str(y_absolute_dif))
    if (y_absolute_dif <= 0.10):

        print("Y-Cords Within Range")
        y_within_range = True
    else:
        print("Y-Cords Not Within Range")

        y_within_range = False
```

Comment: The code is quite hard to read because of all the extra blank lines. Could you remove them please?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yup!

Comment: In the line the error message points to there are 4 "subscript" operations (`[...]`) that could cause this error. Which of those is it? Please split this line into 4 separate operations to find out which of them causes the error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by split it into separate operations? They are connected?

Comment: `obj1` and `obj2` start off as `None` and then your code tries to find values for them. What if there are no values to find? You don't have any error handling code in here that could find the problem before the exception. You could put else clauses after some of those `for`'s so that if the break isn't hit, its called and you know you have an error. And its weird to have nested fors with only one break. That outer for keeps running and you end up with the last `obj1 = object1` in the loop.

Comment: @tdelaney if I didn't start them  as `None` how else would I do it? I understand what you are saying about putting in error handling code but this was working fine just yesterday so I don't understand why it isn't working all of a sudden?

Comment: Apparently, no object ever got assigned to `obj2` so its value remained `None`.

Comment: @martineau why?

Comment: @Agarb - I mentioned the `None` values because of the error is that you are trying to index `None`. It could be that one of those variables was never changed from `None`. You could get rid of the `obj1 = None` completely and then you'll get a different error about referencing a variable before assignment. But that's okay. If you update your code to detect the error before you get that far, you won't hit the error one way or the other. I like not preinitializing if there isn't a sensible default.

Comment: I suppose because `if object1["class_id"] == desired_id1:` was never `True`.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
You posted about 75 lines of code for a 10-line question.  Do not expect us to provide test data or edit a file: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: We expect you to at least look up the error message and try to trace the offending values within your program.  As you've already heard, its *your* responsibility to deconstruct the complex expression to determine which item is unexpectedly `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found something.

```
"class_id":17...
"class_id":17...
"class_id":17...
```

All objects have the same ID? Is it correct so or not?

You need a check `if block` or use a `try except`.

**if block**

```
if obj1 == None:
    print("No, obj1 found!")
    exit(0)
```

**try catch**

```
try:     
    relative_coordinates = object1["relative_coordinates"] 
except:      
    print("No, obj1 found!")
    exit(0)
```

If you search `find_xy(18, 18)` and you have only `"class_id":17` - that can only go wrong without a break position. So you must check if your variable still Nothing or not!

**One point more**
Duplicate code is also bad. Make a function for these, than you can read your code easier!

```
def check_obj():
    #do you staff here...
```

Comment: I think this is due to my model just not being trained that well lol. Can you explain/show what you mean by `if block` or `try except`?

Comment: While your solution was not the correct one, I had put class 18 instead of 17 for my find_xy! Thanks